# UnicodeEncodeError when creating Grass location on Windows

Tags: grass-gis, windows, unicodeencodeerror

i´d tried to create a new location, but i have this in my console, iím learning to use grass gis, so can you help me?

```
   SIG\Archivos Grass\newLocation> no disponible
```

Iniciando GRASS GIS...
ERROR: No se encuentra la LocalizaciÃ³n 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.2\gui\wxpython\gis_set.py", line 531, in OnWizard
    grassdatabase=self.tgisdbase.GetValue())
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.2\gui\wxpython\location_wizard\wizard.py", line 2353, in **init**
    msg = self.OnWizFinished()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.2\gui\wxpython\location_wizard\wizard.py", line 2514, in OnWizFinished
    current_gdb = grass.gisenv()['GISDBASE'].decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 41: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Looks like you have special chars in your paths. Try creating the location on a path with no special chars or whitespaces